# Абстрактное синтаксическое дерево для PHP под .NET

Tags: php, c#, .net, vb.net

В какой структуре можно сохранить **Абстрактное синтаксическое дерево для PHP языка**.
Пишу генераторы кода, но все как то используя простые вещи типа заполнители файлов, сбор методов кантатенацией строк, разными циклами по базе и т.д.
Перебрал уже разную кучу вариантов хранения информации по проекту, но хочется как бы уже прийти к более правильному подходу. Но как это сделать непонятно.
Узнал что есть такое понятие как **Абстрактное синтаксическое дерево**, и хочу поинтересоваться у народа, может кто сталкивался с решением под .NET ?

> Прошу не минусовать и не закрывать вопрос, удалю вопрос через недельку
>   сам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите, для абстрактного синтаксического дерева очевиднее всего использовать такую структуру данных, как дерево. (*Спасибо, Кэп!*)

Встроенного дерева в C# нет, но его легко запрограммировать самостоятельно. Какие вам нужны операции? Например, получение всех дочерних элементов, а также обход (реализация паттерна Visitor).

Пробуем!

```
class TreeNode
{
    public List<TreeNode> Children { get; } = new List<TreeNode>();

    class TreeNode(IEnumerable<TreeNode> children = null)
    {
        if (children != null)
            Children.AddRange(children);
    }

    public abstract Accept(ITreeNodeVisitor visitor);
}

interface ITreeNodeVisitor
{
    void Visit(TreeNode n);
    void Visit(FunctionNode cn);
    void Visit(AssignmentNode an);
    // и т. д.
}
```

Имея это, можно имплементировать конкретные типы узлов:

```
class AdditionNode : TreeNode
{
    public AdditionNode(TreeNode left, TreeNode right) : base(new[] { left, right }) { }
    public override Accept(ITreeNodeVisitor visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
}
```

и т. д.

Итак, у вас будет узел верхнего уровня, у которого будут внутренние узлы и рекурсивно вниз остальное дерево.

(Если вы хотите, чтобы ваши узлы были неизменяемыми, наверное, стоит выставлять не `List<TreeNode>`, а `IReadOnlyList<TreeNode>`.)

Comment: а Expression'ы всякие тут не подойдут?

Comment: @Grundy: Мне в них не нравится то, что (1) они заточены под конструкции C#, а не PHP, и (2) вы не можете управлять дизайном: решение «immutable или нет» уже принято кем-то за вас. Хотя да, был бы вариант или по крайней мере источник вдохновения.